# Blue line on bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

There is a blue line on the bottom of the page on the following link

http://ahato.com/public_html/

How to get rid of it ?
It is not present on either of the other pages...

I have looked into all the sheets and cant get rid of it :(

Answer (score 3):

```
#content - padding bottom should be 0px
```

Comment: Did not helped. Tried doing it

Answer (score 1):

Remove the padding from the bottom of `#content`.  The line is actually the background of the content div below the footer image.

Comment: Tried doing it but it didnot helped :( removed the entire box

Answer (score 1):

Seems you didn't close some element in `<div id="content">`. That's the blue background down there.

On main page, you've got

```
<div id="content">[...]
  <div id="footer">[...]</div>
</div>
```

On the other ones

```
<div id="content">[...]</div>
<div id="footer">[...]</div>
```

I guess it's the `<div class="cls">` in line 222.

Comment: This worked absolutely fine. Thanks a Lot. Its working fine :) Thanks a lot ! It would have taken me ages to figure it out

Comment: Was an easy one using firebug.